# Using the agg-function in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

Say we have a dataset 'data' which contain ID and for each ID we have many 'scores'. For example for ID=1 we have the scores 25,41,23,...,33.

For user 1 I want to calculate the sum of this user's score. In sparkR I do this

```
s = filter(data, data$user==1)
ss = agg(s, summa = sum(s$score) )
```

Now 'ss' gives me the sum of the 'scores' for ID=1. I want to create a dataset where I get the sum of scores for all ID's.

In R I would for example do this

```
newdata=matrix()
for(i in 1: Number of ID's ) {
    s = filter(data, data$user==i)         
newdata[i,] = c(i ,agg(s, summa = sum(s$score)) )
}
```

but this does not work in sparkR. It say "invalid type/length (S4/0) in vector allocation". Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agg works perfectly on groupedData, hence use

```
agg(groupBy(data, user), summa = sum(score))
```

I am not certain if it is necessary to put data$score instead of score, or following the documentation

```
agg(groupBy(data,user), score="sum")
```

Comment: This works successfully. What if ID has 2 scores, namely score1 and score2. I want to turn sum(score1) - sum(score2). In sparkR I do this: bsi=agg(groupBy(all, "user_id"), amount_won="sum" -  amount_spent="sum" ) but it dont run because of the '=' signal.

Comment: first do aggregated <- agg(groupBy(data,user),score1="sum",score2="sum") and then aggregated <- withColumn(aggregated, "total", aggregated$score1-aggregated$score2)

Comment: Makes sense and I can run the first line perfect however when I run line 2 sparkR says "error in col in selecting a method for function withColumn."

Comment: Maybe mutate? mutate(aggregated, total=aggregated$score1-aggregated$score2)

Comment: Still dont work. Hmm.. It should be able to subtract these two measures right?

Comment: Yes, it should if they are doubles. What about aggregated$total <- aggregated$score1-aggregated$score2?

Comment: It works fine with both withColumn, mutate and the last one. I just wrote aggregated[[3]] - aggregated[[2]]. Maybe the error was when I gave them a name in aggregated$score2. Thanks.

Comment: agg(groupBy(data,user), score="sum"). This works for the "sum"-function but how can I make it work for a new function I create ?

Comment: I would suggest you ask new questions, when they concern different questions.
dt <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2),b=c(2,3,3,4))
DT <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,dt)
sumFunction <- function(x){
  sum(x)
}
groupedData <- agg(groupBy(DT,DT$a), score=sumFunction(DT$b))
collect(groupedData)